# Functions; one-one and onto.

Tags: functions

$f: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ is 1-1 and onto.
Define $g: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ 
as $g(x)=1/f(x)$.

Prove that g is also 1-1 and that it maps onto Re+.

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework assignments. Try to show some efford, show us what you already tried, where you got stuck, etc...

Comment: Do you know the defintions of a function, $1-1$ and onto?

Comment: You could define Re+, which is presumably the positive reals.  Now apply what you are given, if $y$ is positive, what is $g(y)$? Use what you know about $f$.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to prove it is g: Re+ onto Re+. I think I can transform g(x)=1/f(x) into f(x)=1/g(x), then say that because g(x) is Re+, a Re+ will always be returned. But I think that's wrong.

Comment: I like the challenge-response approach to quantifiers.  If you want to prove $g$ is onto, if I give you an $m$ you should be able to prove there is an $n$ with $g(n)=m$.  Then to prove $g$ is $1-1$, if I give you $x,y$ with $g(x)=g(y)$ you need to prove $x=y$.  Clearly you can't do that without what you know about $g$ and then $f$

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $f$ is $1-1$ and onto means that $f$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{R}^+$ onto itself, that is: for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there exists (by onto) a unique (by $1-1$) $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $y=f(x)$. Now take $y\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and consider the equation
$$
y=g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}.
$$
How many solutions $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$ are there? If you find one, and only one, for each $y$, this will prove that $g$ is a bijection (i.e. $1-1$ and onto) from $\mathbb{R}^+$ onto itself. There is a simple algebraic operation to perform on the equation above to be able to use the assumption on $f$.